# How to create new file in VIM terminal(shell?)

Tags: vim, makefile

I am working on CURRENTTEXT.txt in vim and would like to make a NEWTEXT.txt on that window.

1. `:vs /space/where/I/want/to/store/new/file`
2. Now I get VIM terminal? shell? on the one side of the window.
   [image]
3. make NEWTEXT.txt 
   but fails

Comment: Did you read the built-in help in Vim for `:h vnew`?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the 'vnew' command. :vnew <filename> works

Answer (score 1):

Vim, though it's a text editor, has quite a rich set of commands for creating and managing multiple "windows".

`:vnew <filename>` creates a vertically-split new window and opens the file. `:vnew` by itself merely creates a blank vertical-split window.

There are many controls available for moving and resizing them, jumping between them, changing the direction of the split... it's impressive.

[Section 6](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-6.1) of the [Vim Frequently Asked Questions](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html) talks about opening and editing multiple existing files and the Vim Wiki talks about all sorts of things, including using [`vnew`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=vnew&go=Try%20exact).

When I'm really digging into a code project I'll have several splits open, sometimes to separate parts of the same file, sometimes diffing two or three files and merging parts of them, sometimes looking at the hexdump of one next to the text version. It's all in Vim's documentation and online help.